# interface php and html, in foreach loop

Tags: php, html, button

I have a PHP page that shows me data from the database. I'm inserting a button that, if pressed, deletes the record. The problem is that if I push the button the action is done on all the records, because I can't uniquely identify the click on the button

some code

```
foreach ( $associati as $associato ) {
    
    echo "<hr />";
    echo "Nome associato : ".$associato->Nome."</br>"; 
    echo "Codice Fiscale : ".$associato->CF."</br>"; 
    echo "<hr />";
    
        if(isset($_POST["numerazione"])){ 
                 echo "Hello world"; //Query for delete 
                  }
    ?>
    
    <form method="POST" action="">
           <input type="submit"
               name="numerazione" 
               value="Elimina utente" 
               onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"
       
       />
         </form>
         <?php
    
}
```

How can I do to uniquely identify the button?

Comment: Do note you can use the HTML element `button`, with which you can set a custom value and still specify the text - `<button type="submit" value="ID_OF_RECORD">Delete</button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a hidden field to each form that contains the unique identifier of the data, that means when you click the button, it will create a POST request, and in that POST request you can get the ID of the clicked record by doing $_POST['unique-id'], also make sure to populate the value of that hidden field using PHP

```
<?php
foreach ( $associati as $associato ) {
    
    echo "<hr />";
    echo "Nome associato : ".$associato->Nome."</br>"; 
    echo "Codice Fiscale : ".$associato->CF."</br>"; 
    echo "<hr />";
    
        if(isset($_POST["numerazione"])){ 
            $numerazione = $_POST["unique-id"];
            echo "Unique record is : ".$numerazione."</br>";
        }
    ?>
    
    <form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="unique-id" value="<?php echo $associato->CF; ?>" />
           <input type="submit"
               name="numerazione" 
               value="Elimina utente" 
               onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"
       
       />
         </form>
         <?php
    
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the unique information (e.g. `$id` or `$associato->id` or whatever the variable which can identify the record) when the form is submitted

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type=hidden name=id value=<?php echo $id; ?>>
       <input type="submit"
           name="numerazione" 
           value="Elimina utente" 
           onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"
   
   />
     </form>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesn't change the result. I think i should change the if statament too, but how?

Comment: tell us the actual delete query you are now using please

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this problem:

```
if(isset($_POST["mod"]) and $_POST["id"]== $associato->ID ){ 
     echo "Hello world";
    
    
    }

?>


<form method="POST" action="">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo $associato->ID; ?>>
   <input type="submit"
       name="mod" 
       value="valore" 
       onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"

    />
</form>
```